# Is it legal to post accepted manuscript to GitHub Pages if embargo has ended for personal website?

Tags: publications, journals, copyright, publishers

I have published my article with Taylor & Francis. For the respective journal, there is no embargo period concerning the publication of the accepted manuscript on the author's personal website - I can do so directly after the article has been published (i.e., now).

I have set up a personal website using GitHub Pages. I would like to post the accepted manuscript there. However, to do so, I need to upload the manuscript to a public GitHub repository - and this seems to be different to a personal website (the embargo period for social networks such as Researchgate etc. has not ended yet).

Can I use GitHub Pages to legally post my accepted manuscript even if it means to upload the manuscript to a public GitHub repository?

Comment: It is unlikely to be a legal (criminal) issue , but perhaps a contractural one. Ask the publisher since they hold the copyright now.

Comment: I already asked them but they did not really reply to my question. I'll probably have to ask them again.

Comment: You're basically asking what the definitions of "personal website" and "social network" are in the agreement (contract) you have with the publisher. We don't have your contract and aren't legal experts to interpret the wording the way a lawyer might. It's possible there is legal ambiguity and you'd want to weigh your legal risks against the benefits, which also isn't really something we can do here. Asking the journal is a good idea, but they don't necessarily need to give you an honest answer: they aren't acting as your legal representation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I should not rely solely on the journal's response.

Comment: If you are a student, you can get a GitHub Pro account for free, which allows you to host GitHub Pages from private repositories

Comment: That's a great tip, thank you very much.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Not only if OP is a student, but also if they are an "educator, faculty member, or researcher."

Comment: I'd honestly just go ahead and do it. Taylor & Francis are not going to sue you. If it is against their policy (and I highly doubt it, since GitHub is a personal website, see e.g. https://jo276.github.io/) they'd first send you a takedown request. You can remove your paper then.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: @Allure There is a subtle point: the problem is not github.io, but the fact that the only way to upload the papers on github.io is including them in a public github repository such as [this one](https://github.com/jo276/jo276.github.io/tree/master/preprints) for your example site.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you could argue that that public GitHub repository is a personal website however. The same logic applies in any case, Taylor & Francis are not going to sue you for putting your files in that public GitHub repository.

Comment: @Allure Why not make your comments an answer?

Comment: @GoodDeeds the question asks "is it legal?" and my comment doesn't address that question.

Comment: Thank you all for these suggestions. I took the safe way and uploaded it on a personal website outside of GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more advice than an answer and you will need to get the definitive answer from the publisher, but my guess is that they won't permit posting the published version other than on a personal site, since things like GitHub have too much visibility.

Posting a preprint might be possible according to the terms, and some publishers actually publish finished work on places like arXiv.

But the advice is to tread carefully here. They own the copyright now.

Comment: After several emails, the publisher has not been able (or willing) to answer this question. I will give up for the moment and think about hosting my own webpage. Thanks for the advice!